Rust generic function with argument copy or borrow depending on concrete type
Is there any way to define a function in Rust with a generically-typed argument which will either copy or (immutably) borrow the argument depending on whether its concrete type is a Copy type?  If that requires a macro, how might one go about writing such a macro--can they be invoked with knowledge of the concrete type being used at compile time?
My specific use case is to try to write a big codebase that's generically defined for native, hardware-accelerated float types (especially f64) or for custom-defined exact-precision number types (especially rational numbers) without having to duplicate upwards of 95% of the code. I would like to avoid indirection for native types, and would like for non-native types (which may be much larger than a CPU register) to not be copied but also not moved and inaccessible after calling the function on them; otherwise, one of these cases will suffer a massive performance hit.
The stub below is obviously invalid Rust code but hopefully clarifies a little--I would like to be able to write the generic function foo that involves, for example, adding numbers, with or without copy semantics depending on the number type--and if foo contains ten thousand such operations, I'd really like to avoid duplicating all that logic.
trait Scalar {}

trait CopiedScalar: Scalar { 
    fn plus(self, other: Self) -> Self;
 }

trait NonCopiedScalar: Scalar {
    fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
 }

fn foo<S: Scalar>(s1: S, s2: S) -> S {
    s1.plus(s2)  // compile error! obviously not even valid for NonCopiedScalar
}


Define a trait, and implement it for owned values for cheap copies and references for expensive.

Thanks!  The missing link for me was that I didn't know traits could be implemented for references, i.e. impl MyTrait for &MyType.  Might seem obvious for a seasoned Rust developer, but I don't believe The Book mentioned this possibility.

The problem is that the two function fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self and fn plus(self, other: Self) -> Self have different signature.
My first thought is to compress both into just take reference, and then do clone or trigger implicit copy.
let say I have struct
#[derive(Clone, Default, Debug)]
pub struct ILikeBigStruct {
    pub and: f64,
    pub i: f64,
    pub can: f64,
    pub not: f64,
    pub lie: f64,
}

Both Take Reference
Adding plus(&self, other:&Self) to trait Scalar, and implement it for f64 and ILikeBigStruct.
this will implicit copy f64, and do not clone/copy ILikeBigStruct, but this cause a redirection for f64.
mod method1 {
    use std::ops::Add;

    use crate::ILikeBigStruct;

    pub trait Scalar {
        fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
    }

    impl Scalar for f64 {
        fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self {
            self.add(other) // implicit copy
        }
    }

    impl Scalar for ILikeBigStruct {
        fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self {
            ILikeBigStruct {
                and: self.and + other.and,
                i: self.i + other.i,
                can: self.can + other.can,
                not: self.not + other.not,
                lie: self.lie + other.lie,
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn foo<S: Scalar>(s1: &S, s2: &S) -> S {
        s1.plus(s2)
    }
}

Impl for Reference
the other way I think of is to implement the trait for &ILikeBigStruct instead, however it required a associate type in the trait.
but if it were to grow more complex, prepare for some lifetime shenanigans down the road.
mod method2 {
    use crate::ILikeBigStruct;
    pub trait Scalar {
        type PlusOutput;
        fn plus(self, other: Self) -> Self::PlusOutput;
    }

    impl Scalar for f64 {
        type PlusOutput = f64;
        fn plus(self, other: Self) -> Self::PlusOutput {
            self + other
        }
    }

    impl Scalar for &ILikeBigStruct {
        type PlusOutput = ILikeBigStruct;
        fn plus(self, other: Self) -> Self::PlusOutput {
            ILikeBigStruct {
                and: self.and + other.and,
                i: self.i + other.i,
                can: self.can + other.can,
                not: self.not + other.not,
                lie: self.lie + other.lie,
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn foo<S: Scalar>(s1: S, s2: S) -> S::PlusOutput {
        s1.plus(s2)
    }
}

Testing
I did some testing for performance, not really conclusive, seem to be similar, sensitive to benching parameter.
